# Code to create a Batch file that disable the option "hide protected operating system files"

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-line

I would like to create a batch file to disable Windows option "hide protected operating system files" (You can see in the image in attachment the option that I want disable).

Can you help me?

Thank you very much

[image: Disable hide protected operating system files].

Comment: ```@%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /V "ShowSuperHidden" /T Reg_DWord /D 1 /F 1>NUL``` is the single line you need. Please be aware that there is a strong likelihood that Windows Explorer will need to be restarted for the actual change to be reflected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the registry setting `ShowSuperHidden` with the following command:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v "ShowSuperHidden" /t REG_DWORD /d "1" /f
```

It sets this registry entry to `TRUE`=`1` to show these system files.
Restarting the "explorer.exe" may be necessary

```
taskkill /im explorer.exe /f
explorer
```

The second command restarts `explorer.exe`.
A more complete list of these registry modifications [can be found at GitHUB](https://gist.github.com/shoober420/c9c2d2d969df12c95b11ae731d52c5f0).

Comment: This `code taskkill /im explorer.exe /f` left my windows without windows bar and without access to the folders, only access to the browser, I had to restart the computer by task manager, is normal?

But the code worked fine to disable the option!

Comment: Sorry. I was unsure to include the restart. Often Windows initiates this automatically. I added the command explicitly. Simply restarting `explorer.exe` will give you back the windows bar and all the other functions of the explorer. So add this as the line after the taskkill.